# How to handle buffer and secondary storage with PostgreSQL Server Programming (SPI)?

Tags: postgresql, server

I am wondering where/how to let PostgreSQL (9.6) handle memory issues between secondary storage (e.g. Hard Drives) and memory buffers?

For example, how to load relevant data into memory when some tuples being queried are not in the buffer; and how to flush some data to disk when the memory buffer is full?

I haven't done server programming before. But when I looked at the [Server Programming Interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/spi.html) and the section about [memory management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/spi-memory.html), I can't find any mention of "secondary storage" or "buffer" etc. Where are such issues handled?

Can anyone give some pointers about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused here.

The memory management functions you reference above are to allocate and manage memory that remains allocated after your function has finished (but is freed when the calling statement ends), e.g. to contain results to return to the caller of the function.

Storage management and data buffering happen on a different, much lower, level, and you cannot influence that via SPI. SPI is just an interface for C code running in the server to run SQL statements. As far as shared buffers are concerned, it does not make a difference whether you issue a query from `psql` or via SPI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `Storage management and data buffering happen on a different, much lower, level, and you cannot influence that via SPI.`. So is there a way outside of SPI to make sure that server extensions, e.g.,  can handle storage management? i.e. do not generate Out of Memory errors because of main memory constraints.

Comment: For that you have to configure the operating system and database parameters correctly. There is no way to avoid an OOM if you run out of memory... What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: For example, write a custom SQL function in C that do not OOM if the needed data for the function exceeds physical memory but not hard disk space.

Comment: Then the right approach is not to bring the whole machine to its knees, but to write your function so that it stores data in a temporary file. See the functions in `src/backend/storage/file/buffile.c`

Comment: `src/backend/storage/file/buffile.c`. Thanks for the pointer. I think that's what I am looking for.